# How solve "Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!"

Tags: qt, windows-10, qmake

I'm trying to use **cmake** for a project that **has a lot of dependencies**.
I updated to **Windows 10** some week ago, starting from Windows 7, and now I get this error.

How can I solve this problem considering I won't downgrade to Windows 7?

Thanks to all

Comment: This is just a warning.

Comment: Wait for the next release of Qt, and hope it doesn't break your old code, like it happened for me with Qt 5.5 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you use Qt version that was released before Windows 8 release. It might be Qt 4.8.x. To suspend the warning you need to update your Qt version or simply ignore that warning.

**UPDATE**

If the warning message makes real trouble, you can try to filter it out in the following way:

```
 #include <qapplication.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const char *msg)
 {
     switch (type) {
     case QtDebugMsg:
         fprintf(stderr, "Debug: %s\n", msg);
         break;
     case QtWarningMsg:
         if (strstr(msg, "Qt: Untested Windows version") == 0) {
             // Print warning if it is not "Qt: Untested Windows..."
             fprintf(stderr, "Warning: %s\n", msg);
         }
         break;
     case QtCriticalMsg:
         fprintf(stderr, "Critical: %s\n", msg);
         break;
     case QtFatalMsg:
         fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: %s\n", msg);
         abort();
     }
 }

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
     qInstallMsgHandler(myMessageOutput);
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     ...
     return app.exec();
 }
```

Comment: I'm using QMake version 3.0 and Qt 5.4.2. I'm new to Qt and qmake, i downloaded it some weeks ago.

Could this warning bring problems to project's building?

Comment: @Gennaro, no, I don't think it will make any problem with compiling the project.