# How to read custom c++ dll file

Tags: ruby, winapi

I'm trying to read custom c++ dll file with the following code.

```
require 'ffi'
require 'Win32API'

module Test
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib 'C:\Users\MyLab\Desktop\TestApi\TestAPI'
  attach_function :getInformation, [] ,:string    
  # import, export = "0", calltype = :stdcall
  # codeGen = Win32API.new("TestAPI", "getInformation", [], 'I').call()
end
puts Test.getInformation
```

But it gives the following error:

```
Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!
```

How can I fix it? What's the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32966226/how-solve-qt-untested-windows-version-10-0-detected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How solve "Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32966226/how-solve-qt-untested-windows-version-10-0-detected)

Comment: but dll file is not mine, and it works correctly in  c#

Comment: The library you are using actively refuses to execute on the version of Windows you are running. That's a deliberate decision made by the vendor of the library. Either run your code on a supported version of Windows, or ask the vendor of the library to provide a binary that supports your intended target version of Windows. Or run your application in compatibility mode.